# File Not Showing

Tags: python

This is copied straight out of my IDLE session. I'm trying to read a file called `readListing.txt` and `writeListing.txt` however only one will open.

Here is me reading the directory and printing out it's contents and then doing a `os.path.exists` to see if it's there. Very bizarre!

```
>>> listDir = os.listdir("C:\Users\me\Desktop\TestingDocuments")
>>> for d in listDir:
    print d

CopyFiles.py
FileUtil.py
ReadDirectory.py
readListing.txt
TestGen
writeListing.txt

>>> os.path.exists("C:\Users\me\Desktop\TestingDocuments\writeListing.txt")
True
>>> os.path.exists("C:\Users\me\Desktop\TestingDocuments\readListing.txt")
False
```

Comment: Change `print d` to `print repr(d)`.  There may be trailing spaces that are part of the file name.

Comment: Though it wasn't the problem, that's useful to know, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to be careful using backslashes in strings. The second fails because '\r' is a carriage return. I suggest you use raw strings if you want to use strings of this kind:

```
os.path.exists(r"C:\Users\mcmullma\Desktop\TestingDocuments\readListing.txt")
```

If you use a raw string (prefix with r), then the escape sequences are not interpreted in the string.

Comment: And fwiw, I'm pretty sure windows these days supports the use of forward slashes too.